# possible for Okular to remember the last "session" & re-open the last open files?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, okular

Is it possible for Okular to remember the last "session" & re-open the last open files if you close and re-open it? I have Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE and Okular v. 21.12.3. I'm not sure if this feature was added in a more-recent version.